# Custom labelling of randomly generated unitaries in Qiskit

Tags: programming, qiskit

I'm writing a program in Qiskit involving the generation of Haar-random unitaries. Is there a way to label each unitary such that the label appears instead of 'unitary' when I draw the circuit?

```
qc = qiskit.QuantumCircuit(2,1)
randUnitary = qiskit.quantum_info.random_unitary(4)
qc.append(randUnitary,[0,1])
qc.draw()
```

[image: Circuit output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you can assign a label to a `Gate` or an `Instruction` object for this. For example, something like:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.extensions import UnitaryGate
from qiskit.quantum_info import random_unitary

qc = QuantumCircuit(2,1)
randUnitary = UnitaryGate(random_unitary(4), label='My Special Unitary')
qc.append(randUnitary, [0,1])
qc.draw()
```

which yields

[image: Unitary with label]